# Geolocation does not work on smartphone

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I want to implement geolocation in my app.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {               
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, errorGettingPosition);
}

function getPosition(position) {
           var myLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
           var myLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
           var radiusEarth = 6371;

           myLongitude = myLongitude * (Math.PI / 180);
           myLatitude = myLatitude * (Math.PI / 180);

           var x0 = myLongitude * radiusEarth * Math.cos(myLatitude);
           var y0 = myLatitude * radiusEarth;

           for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
              var vendorLongitude = list[i].Longitude = list[i].Longitude * (Math.PI / 180);
              var vendorLatitude = list[i].Latitude = list[i].Latitude * (Math.PI / 180);
              var x1 = vendorLongitude * radiusEarth * Math.cos(vendorLatitude);
              var y1 = vendorLatitude * radiusEarth;

              var dx = x0 - x1;
              var dy = y0 - y1;

              var d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

              if (d < 1) {
                 list[i].Distance = Math.round(d * 1000) + " m";
              } else {
                 list[i].Distance = Math.round(d * 10) / 10 + " km";
              }
           }
           //add vendors to scope
           $scope.vendors = list;
}

function errorGettingPosition(err) {
           if (err.code == 1) {
              alert("User denied geolocation.");
           }
           else if (err.code == 2) {
              alert("Position unavailable.");
           }
           else if (err.code == 3) {
              alert("Timeout expired.");
           }
           else {
              alert("ERROR:" + err.message);
           }
 }
```

I have written these codelines. In browser on computers it will work perfectly, but if I install this app on my smartphone (Android, version 5.1.1) it does not work and I don't know why. It also not enters the error function on smartphone.

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

this one may enter in to error function

```
function initiate_watchlocation() {
    if (watchProcess == null) {
        watchProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
}

var onSuccess = function(position) {
    var myLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var myLongitude = position.coords.longitude;

    };

    function onError(error) {
            alert_box('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

consider running it in document.ready.

Comment: yeah i could see. use `watchPosition` and try to call this function on document ready.

Comment: app which runs html or js file in android needs webview. which is just like browser. it will load document just like browser. in computer browser or mobile browser, it has many features and functions and application `webview` is compact and it will only load a document. and if you are using simple `webview` for app please consider using frame works like `phonegap`.

Comment: or atleast consider this `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){//your code}`

Answer (score 0):

It is very special. When the app loads the site, it starts with the getCurrentPosition() function. Then I can step through, nothing happens. But after a few seconds (about 5) it will go through the success callback. And I save the results in $scope, because I work with AngularJS. But in the GUI I cannot recognize anything about the positions longitude and latitude.

Comment: Found out: $scope.$apply() helped me to get the actual data.